# ReqactQuill Editor resizing on long text

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Having an issue with the React-Quill (not necessarily the package itself) but when I paste (or type) a large amount of text into the editor, it resizes instead of scrolls.  I am using the editor in flex boxes - which is what I assume the problem to be but I cannot see how to get around it.

How do I keep the text editor contained within the div it is placed?

[Code Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-example-forked-j6w8u?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: Hi:) Just add `div.msg-container` a style `height:200px` or similar.

Comment: The purpose of using the flex was to allow the editor to fill the contents of the `div` so I didn't have to fix the height.